# Declaring Static Property While Including Another Static Property

Tags: php, oop, php-7

Is it possible to define a static property while including another static property with-in it? Something like the following example of code:

```
class Foo {
    public static $foo = array(Bar::$bar);
}

class Bar {
    public static $bar = "Hello";
}
```

Obviously this doesn't compile, and causes the following error:

**Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations**

Is there any way to call upon another classes static / constants while declaring your own? I'm trying to cut down on code reuse, and this would be the easiest way for me to do it.

Obviously there will be no way to do this prior to PHP 5.6, so I am using PHP 7/7.1.

Comment: according to [properties declaration man page](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) , "This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make one of the classes have a `const`. This works in 5.6 and later

```
class Foo {
    const CON = 'Yep';
}

class BAR {
    public static $var = Foo::CON;
}
echo BAR::$var;
```

Comment: I'm thinking about changing all of these to const since they don't change anyways. As long as I can access Class constants without instantiating the class, that will work. Having 5.6 support would also be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a constant with the first class variable, and use it in the second one, for example:

```
class Bar {
    public static $bar = 'Hello';
}

define('bar_constant', Bar::$bar);

class Foo {
    public static $foo = array(bar_constant);
}

// now Foo::$foo = array('Hello')
```

Comment: This isn't a bad solution either, but I want to avoid putting any code outside of the class declarations.